# placing "which" confusing to keep remaining parts

Tags: clauses, relative-pronouns

> 1. These relations may create cross borders with another cycle on some
>      occasions.
> 2. Cross borders can be used to identify segmentation-induced erroneous
>      places because a plane graph should not consist of any cross borders.

According to my feeling, I combined them as,

> These relations may create cross borders with another cycle on some
>   occasions ***which*** can be used to identify segmentation-induced
>   erroneous places because a plane graph should not consist of any cross
>   borders.

But I feel this second part should be joined like

These relations may create cross borders *which can be used to identify ....*.
Then I am confused how remaining part of the first section can hold "*with another cycle on some occasions*".

Any idea on this?

Comment: This feels like writing advice. Smarter people than I (e.g., StoneyB) would probably have much better advice, but I might say, "On some occasions these relations may create cross borders with another cycle, and because a plane graph should not consist of any cross borders, these can be used to identify segmentation-induced fault locations."  I replaced "erroneous places" with "fault locations" because "erroneous places" isn't quite idiomatic.  I don't know whether "fault locations" fits your technical jargon though.

Comment: @Jim I think your solution is just dandy - if you will post it as an answer I will upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution would be to rewrite it something like:

> "On some occasions these relations may create cross borders with another cycle, and because a plane graph should not consist of any cross borders, these can be used to identify segmentation-induced fault locations."

I replaced "erroneous places" with "fault locations" because "erroneous places" isn't quite idiomatic. I don't know whether "fault locations" fits your technical jargon though.